# JQuery Mobile and PHP

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I am using Dreamweaver with JQuery Mobile to create a web site.

I know that in JQuery Mobile  I have to include `rel="external" to link to an external file.

In my case, as I am using Dreamweaver's generated code, I need to change it at this point:

```
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "menu.php";
if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
```

I have tried putting

```
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "menu.php rel='external'";
```

but it doesn´t work.

Any help is welcome.

UPDATED

This the URL showed in the browser before the user logs in

```
http://.../obrasbiesa/login.php
```

And this is the URL showed in the browser after login, it should be

```
http://.../obrasbiesa/menu.php
```

but it is

```
http://.../obrasbiesa/login.php#/obrasbiesa/login.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you've posted has quite a bit of syntax errors.

Try this :

```
// Set Previous Url
$_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/obrasbiesa/menu.php';

// Redirect
if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && !empty($_SESSION['PrevUrl'])) {
    header("Location: " . $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] );
} else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed ); // p.s. is this variable being set?
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the solution. I will put the URLs showed in the browser before and after login...may be it helps you finding the issue.

Comment: can you show us the code that is setting the value to `$_SESSION['PrevUrl']` - i believe this is where the issue is. Full url is not being set correctly;

Comment: Thank you Latheesan, don't worry, I have found the problem, it has nothing to do with the piece of code from my question, it was a simple data-ajax="false" param inside a form. Thank you in any way.